# Cursor help on large spatial query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, cursor

I have two very large tables on which I want to perform a spatial query.

```
UPDATE table_a
    SET att_1 = b.att_1, att_2 = b.att_2
    FROM table_a AS a
        JOIN table_b AS b
            ON ST_Contains(a.geom,b.geom);
```

I am rather new to cursors, but here is my current attempt:

```
DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT att_1, att_2 FROM table_a;


OPEN curs1

FETCH NEXT FROM curs1
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE table_a
        SET att_1 = b.att_1, att_2 = b.att_2
        FROM table_a AS a
            JOIN table_b AS b
                ON ST_Contains(a.geom,b.geom)
        WHERE CURRENT OF curs1

        FETCH NEXT FROM curs1
    END

CLOSE curs1
DEALLOCATE curs1 ;
```

My current error is:

> ```
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "OPEN"
>
> LINE 5: OPEN curs1
> ```

You may have surmised that all I want to do is take two attributes from my second table and add them to my first table where they meet spatially (table a is polygon data and table b is point data).

I am currently using Postgres 9.4 with PostGIS 1.2.

The two tables are massive, 25 million and 5 million respectively. This is why I need to go down the cursor route, the straight update query simply fails with such large datasets.

Comment: I believe the open needs to be inside a begin. However, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624036/postgresql-cursors). Cursors are very rarely used in Postgres. You should be able to write the above as a simple `update .... where st_contains(a.geom, b.geom)`; It will be vastly slower using a cursor. If you think you need a cursor over a straight update for some other reason (memory?), please update the question to explain why.

Comment: Don't [cross-post questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36400371/327026)

Comment: @MikeT - Thanks, I have removed it from overflow. Someone just mentioned here would be more appropriate.